# MySQL db creation in Ansible

Tags: mysql, ansible

I'm getting to grips with Ansible, but I'm struggling to create a new database on the MySQL that I've installed and started its service.

The error I keep getting is;

> failed: [prod-wp] => {"failed": true} msg: unable to connect to
>   database, check login_user and login_password are correct or ~/.my.cnf
>   has the credentials

YML below, can you help?

# GET MySQL RUNNING

```
- name: Start the MySQL service
  sudo: yes
  service: 
    name: mysql 
    state: started
    enabled: true
- name: update mysql root password for all root accounts
  sudo: yes
  mysql_user: 
    name: root 
    host: "{{ item }}" 
    password: "pws"
    login_user: root
    login_password: "pws"
    check_implicit_admin: yes
    priv: "*.*:ALL,GRANT"
  with_items:
  - "{{ ansible_hostname }}"
  - 127.0.0.1
  - 1
  - localhost
```

# Commands to setup WordPress

```
- name: Create a new database
  mysql_db: name=demo state=present collation=utf8_general_ci
- name: Create a database user
  mysql_user: name=root password=pws priv=*.*:ALL host=localhost
```

Answer (score 2):

Now this is a guess, because your `password` and `login_password` are identical. By default MySQL sets an empty password for user `root` and I guess this is the reason why you want to change it in the first place. But you can not log in with the `pws` password because you first have to set it... does that make sense?

So try to leave the `login_password` empty:

```
login_password: ""
```

or remove the line completely.

Answer (score 2):

Once we set a root password, we use a `/root/.my.cnf` config file so that the various Ansible tasks have access to it in the future:

```
- name: create mysql database
  mysql_db: name=local state=present
- name: set mysql root password
  mysql_user: name=root host=localhost password=xxxxxx
- name: store mysql root password
  copy: src=files/mysql-user.cnf dest=/root/.my.cnf
```

`files/mysql-user.cnf` contains:

```
[client]
user=root
password=xxxxxx

[mysql]
user=root
password=xxxxxx

[mysqldump]
user=root
password=xxxxxx

[mysqldiff]
user=root
password=xxxxxx
```